# Font warning using memoir

Tags: fonts, memoir

I am getting the following font warning using memoir:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shapre `T1/cmss/bx/sc`undefined (Font) using `T1/cmss/bx/n'instead on input line 14
```

where line 14 points to where I have `\mainmatter` in my source file.

Here is the source code

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}   
\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{madsen}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\end{document}
```

which should select the Palatino font.

## Update

If I use the sniplet below from egreg's answer:

```
\sbox0{\sffamily x}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmss/bx/n}{} 
\chapterstyle{madsen}
```

the warning goes away, but I get some font artifacts:

[image]

With this, is there a way to force `\chapterstyle{madsen}` to use `palatino`?

Comment: You're requesting somewhere a small caps boldface sans serif font which doesn't exist in the Computer Modern Sans Serif family. It's a glitch of the chapter style, it seems.

Comment: Moreover, `\fontfamily{ppl}` is not the correct way to define Palatino as the default font: `\usepackage{mathpazo}` is the right way.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. The warning goes away when I comment out the line `\chapterstyle{madsen}`, so I guess, from your comment, that the glitch is on that style. In your experience, is this something that may require a big fix?

Comment: why would it select the palatino font without calling the `palatino` package? When compiling it with `\usepackage{palatino}`, it only yells some `Overfull \hbox` warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an innocuous warning. If you really want it to disappear, then write

```
\sbox0{\sffamily x}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmss/bx/n}{} 
\chapterstyle{madsen}
```

The first line loads the sans serif family, the second one declares that the substitution which triggers the warning should be silent.

Note that in order to get Palatino as the main text font you should load

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

(`texdoc psnfss` will shed some light on this).

For getting the chapter heading all in Palatino, use this code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}   

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makechapterstyle{madsenserif}{% requires graphicx package
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
      \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
        \chapnamefont\bfseries\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \chapnamefont \phantom{\printchaptername \chapternamenum%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
        \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
          \chapnamefont\bfseries 1}%
      }%
    }%
    \afterchapternum %
  }%

  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{%
    \par\hspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}}
\chapterstyle{madsenserif}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg! The warning went away. Is there a way to force `\chapterstyle{madsen}` to use `palatino`?

Comment: @roseck Yes: say `\usepackage{mathpazo}` in the document preamble.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I did that already (my code above reflects that change) but somehow the font of the chapter title didn't change.

Comment: @roseck That's what the style is supposed to do: the title is typeset in a sans serif font.

Comment: I see, so if I understand correctly, there is no easy way to make it look like the regular body text in my picture (i.e. make the chapter title use the serif palatino font). Is that correct?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks @egreg. This answer is very instructional.